# How can I tell how much my system is swapping?

Tags: swap

Is there a good way to see how much my system (for example how frequently, how much  swap space it is using each time/ on average) is using the swap space during various tasks?

Answer (score 8):

You can use `sar -B 1` to get a realtime view of this information (change `1` to the update interval you want).

The output looks like this:

```
08:11:54 PM  pgpgin/s pgpgout/s   fault/s  majflt/s  pgfree/s pgscank/s pgscand/s pgsteal/s    %vmeff
08:11:55 PM      0.00      0.00     24.00      0.00     57.00      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00
08:11:56 PM      0.00      0.00     23.53      0.00     53.92      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00
08:11:57 PM      0.00      0.00     16.00      0.00     53.00      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00
```

- pgpgin/s -
  Total number of kilobytes the system paged in from disk per second.
- pgpgout/s -
  Total number of kilobytes the system paged out to disk per second.
- fault/s -
  Number of page faults (major + minor) made by the system per second.  This is not a count of page faults that generate I/O,  because some page faults can be resolved without I/O.
- majflt/s -
  Number of major faults the system has made per second, those which have required loading a memory page from disk.
- pgfree/s -
  Number of pages placed on the free list by the system per second.
- pgscank/s -
  Number of pages scanned by the kswapd daemon per second.
- pgscand/s -
  Number of pages scanned directly per second.
- pgsteal/s -
  Number of pages the system has reclaimed from cache (pagecache and swapcache) per second to satisfy its memory demands.

Comment: Sar comes with **sa1** a script that can collect daily usage of different system activity metrics, pagination included (see "man sa1", "man sadc").